# Help with RegEx needed in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this kind of strings...

```
---Quote (Originally by cyberpig)---
I thought is use hair dryer on the GPU? Put whole card in oven PCB won't melt meh?
---End Quote---
back in my old company, when we do such troubleshooting we usually use a blower/dryer meant for pcb components.
```

from those, I want to strip out all the text between `---Quote` and `Quote---` , including them.
Kindly provide a PHP function please.

Thx

Comment: There are entirely too many questions on regular expressions, most of which at least deal with a problem. You are simply asking for us to complete a task for you, kindly, without even trying to understand it. That is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: I understand coreyward, but i needed help badly. And I'll never understand RegEx i guess.

Comment: With that attitude, how could you ever expect to?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newText = preg_replace('/---Quote.*?---.*?---End Quote---/s', '', $oldText);
```

Tested on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
preg_replace("#---Quote(.|\n)*Quote---#m", "", $str);
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have a `g` pattern modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/-{3}Quote(?:.\n)*-{3}End Quote-{3}/', '', $str);
```